# How to play audiofiles one by one

Tags: android

So I have ann array with audiofiles ids. But it depends on user how many ids will be there (he  types "a" and R.raw.a appears in array). How can I play this sounds one after another using MediaPlayer. I think I should use OnCompletionListener, but I don't know how many sounds ids will be in array. Should I use

```
for(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set MediaPlayer for OnCompletionListener

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    MediaPlayer player = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Called when playback is complete
        //Play a next song
        ...
    }
}
```

Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use IntentService to play song. All songs started using [intentservice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) will be in queue. It will play one after other.